# Will my users old cache file not render my new design correctly?

Tags: html, css, caching, browser

I may be wrong by saying it is my users browser but i have a question when updating my online store.

I have recently redesigned my homepage store which i am currently in the middle of completing.

It can be found through http://www.hot-water-cylinders.com/

Bascially, i realized going through a computer that had already been to the website and stored it in its cache everything was out of place, the image files linked into the document where the old ones use and basically clearing my browsers data was the only way of fixing the layout,

My question is that will my returning visitors have to deal with this issue too, like having to clear their cache and is the anyway to prevent this?

Thanks,

Kieren.

Answer (score 3):

This is how HTTP caching is supposed to work.

The best way to avoid this is to make the resource URL:s unique. If you're doing all of this manually try putting the new resources in a versioned folder (/2.0/css, /2.0/img, etc).

Answer (score 0):

At first, yes, but the browser cache usually least for only a day. If you want to prevent any cache you need to add a version to your style request as below

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/my/css/mystyle.css?v=1">
```

The `v` parameter is relative to your css version, when you upload a new style version you'll need to change the version.